# How to increase storage space on Homestead Vagrant?

Tags: ubuntu, vagrant, virtualbox, homestead

I need to learn how increase the storage size of all partitions of Ubuntu on my homestead vagrant system.

Currently I came across a annoying problem of lack of storage space in my Homestead/Vagrant/VMBox installation. After reading some online tutorials, I believe I have gathered some evidence about what I need to do.

Until now I have been able to do the following:

1. Create a copy of the file "C:\Users\MyUser\VirtualBox VMs\homestead-7\ubuntu-18.04-amd64-disk001.vmdk" in the ".vdi" extention through the "clonehd" function of the "VBoxManage" on CMD with the following command:

```
C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox> VBoxManage clonehd "C:\Users\MyUser\VirtualBox VMs\homestead-7\ubuntu-18.04-amd64-disk001.vmdk" "C: \BKP_HD_VAGRANT\cloned.vdi" --format vdi
```

2. Increase the Capacity of the VDI Copy via CMD with the command:

```
C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox> VBoxManage modifyhd "C:\bkp_hd_vagrant\cloned.vdi" --resize 209715
```

3. Change the Sata Controller storage reference in the VMBox to the new file "cloned.vdi"

Unfortunately from now on I’ve not been able to continue.
I’ve tried to execute the steps listed on the following tutorial but nothing works.

https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/guides/a-guide-to-extending-homestead-storage-capacity

However, my configuration is very different from what is shown in the images in this guide as you can see below.

```
Disk /dev/sda: 195.3 GiB, 209715200000 bytes, 409600000 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0xeb0a5011

Device     Boot Start       End   Sectors Size Id Type
/dev/sda1  *     2048 134215679 134213632  64G 8e Linux LVM


Disk /dev/mapper/vagrant--vg-root: 63 GiB, 67687677952 bytes, 132202496 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/mapper/vagrant--vg-swap_1: 980 MiB, 1027604480 bytes, 2007040 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
```

```
Filesystem                     1K-blocks      Used Available Use% Mounted on
udev                             4053320         0   4053320   0% /dev
tmpfs                             816832      6504    810328   1% /run
/dev/mapper/vagrant--vg-root    64800356  10692068  50786844  18% /
tmpfs                            4084152         8   4084144   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs                               5120         0      5120   0% /run/lock
tmpfs                            4084152         0   4084152   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
vagrant                        109370364  97896548  11473816  90% /vagrant
home_vagrant_code              976629756 146938732 829691024  16% /home/vagrant/code
home_vagrant_backup            976629756 146938732 829691024  16% /home/vagrant/backup
home_vagrant_backup_importacao 976629756 146938732 829691024  16% /home/vagrant/backup_importacao
tmpfs                             816828         0    816828   0% /run/user/1000
```

```
Welcome to fdisk (util-linux 2.31.1).
Changes will remain in memory only, until you decide to write them.
Be careful before using the write command.


Command (m for help): p
Disk /dev/sda: 195.3 GiB, 209715200000 bytes, 409600000 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0xeb0a5011

Device     Boot Start       End   Sectors Size Id Type
/dev/sda1  *     2048 134215679 134213632  64G 8e Linux LVM
```

I need to extend the size of the partitions so vagrant can use all the size available on my new "cloned.vdi" file.

Would anyone know what I should do to adapt this guide to be able to solve my problem taking into account my current situation?

Comment: From your description, parted should do what you want, namely extending partitions. You should be able to follow these instructions: `https://www.gnu.org/software/parted/manual/html_node/parted_31.html`. If you're struggling with the CLI, you could try gparted. The very easiest way to make more storage available to your VBox would be to just add a second HDD through the VirtualBox web interface.

Comment: In fact I just realize that i need to increase this disk:

Disk /dev/mapper/vagrant--vg-root

Can you lead me to a tutorial or manual to learn how to do that?